# Check for change in input

Tags: verilog, dsp

I have a problem checking for the change in input, that is when A changes value x changes state. where a is an N-bit input and "x" is a single bit out
[image: a block diagram to check for change in A]

Comment: What platform are you trying to implement this on?

Comment: Simply latch the value on each clock, bitwise xor with the value from the previous clock. If the result is non-zero, the value has changed.

Comment: What's the relationship between input and output?

Comment: the output is the same as the input, x changes state from 1 to 0 and vice versa when there is a new data on the input

Comment: i was able to come up with this design please take a look at it.
module change_in_a (Ain, Aout, clk, rst_n, xout);
input  wire [31:0] Ain;
input clk,rst_n;
output   [31:0] Aout;
output reg xout;
reg P_Ain =0;
reg check;

 assign  Aout= Ain;

 always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
    begin
   if (!rst_n)
    begin
    xout  <= 1'b0;
    P_Ain =0;
    end
      else
    begin
    P_Ain <= Ain;
    check = Ain ^ P_Ain;
    if (check == 0)
    xout <= xout;
    else 
    xout =~xout;
    end
   
 end
 endmodule
is there any problem with it and how can i make it better? thanks @caveman

Answer (score 1):

This would be one possible implementation:

```
module demo(clk, rst, A, Aq, X);
    parameter N = 8;
    input clk, rst;
    input [N-1:0] A;
    output reg [N-1:0] Aq;
    output reg X;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (rst)
            X <= 0;
        else if (A != Aq)
            X <= !X;
        Aq <= A;
    end
endmodule
```